# Encoding of javamail is driving me Crazy

Tags: java, email, encoding, utf-8

I have build a simple java class to test mail sending with accents.

I take a string from an UTF8 postgres database and export it in a file and send this thru a mail.
I see the foolowing things :
1) when I execute without -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 the string in the file is OK but the mail is KO
2) when I execute with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 the string in the file is KO but the mail is OK if I do not specify the charset (messageBodyPart.setContent( sb.toString(), "text/html");
3) when I execute with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 the string in the file is KO but the mail is KO if I specify the charset (messageBodyPart.setContent( sb.toString(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

I really do not understand. Thanks for your help.
I hope to be clear.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on such a global setting anyway. What some code does depends on the code. We can't tell why some code does what it does without seeing the code, because we're not extra-lucid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mail.mime.charset](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) system property to set the JavaMail charset.  You can call [MimeUtility.getDefaultJavaCharset()](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#getDefaultJavaCharset()) to see that it is set correctly.